# Sum of the digits of $101^6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the sum of the digits of $101^6$? I can calculate it by binomial coefficients writing as $(100+1)^6$ but i look for a smarter way. Is there any other way to calculate this without a calculator?

Comment: I'd argue that binomial coefficients are the right way to go here, and I expect any better solution will just be a different way of writing out binomials.

Comment: I fully agree with @B. Mehta

Comment: @JeanMarie that works up to exponent $4,$ it fails for larger exponents because there are some "carries." I just took $101^3 = 1030301$ and carefully squared it by hand. Digit sum  is not 64.

Comment: @Will Nagy Your result "by hand" must be 106152015061 |with carries that at most impact the next "level" (conclusion : sum of digits = 28) This is exactly the same result that one obtains by directly computing, using binomial coefficients $10^{12}+6*10^{10}+15*10^8+20*10^{6}+15*10^4+6*10^2+1$

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, I see that in theanswer below as well. I thought people were thinking in terms of the actual sum of binomial coefficients being $2^6,$ that was my first guess, but wrong. Oh, my last name is not Nagy, it is the uncommon Jagy.

Comment: @Will Jagy Sorry, the second time I miswrite your name...

Answer (score 2):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=101%5E6

What a big surprise: binomials all over the place:

1061520150601

(1+6+1+5)*2 + 2

28

Comment: so, if used literally, this method would fail beginning at exponent 9, since (9 choose 4) = 126 is bigger than 100, get some "carries"

Comment: yes, that is why 101 was used. It works for exponent 6, unlike 11, that starts failing at exponent 5.